# Eagle: IC package variant, different pins bonded out

Tags: fpga, components, eaglecad, packages

I'm trying to create an Eagle component for the Altera EP4CE22, which comes in BGA and SMD packages, where different pins are actually available on the outside of the package.

Is it possible to reuse the same symbol for both, not connecting the unavailable pins to outside pads, or do I need to create two different symbols?

If I need two different symbols, is it possible to create them so that it's easy to move between them (realistically, SMD -> BGA when I need more I/O lines)?

Comment: I guess you're talking about EAGLE?

Comment: Yes; no idea why it sorted the "fpga" tag in front.

Comment: It is sorted by the number of questions containing that tag.